# Highlighting Sql code in text area

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a textarea in which I have to show some sql commands.I don't want to present it as a normal text to user,I have to format it as SQL(as in management studio).Is there any opensource library (Javascript) out there that can help me achieve my goal? I am currently using c# as backend.

Comment: Show your code and what is done so far

Answer (score 7):

As you say you're using a TextArea, that means that the user can edit the content of it, then i recommend you to use a web code editor plugin like [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) or [Code Mirror](https://codemirror.net/) (both implemented in frontend).

If the user doesn't need to edit that code and only need to read it, then you can highlight the snippet using a Syntax highlighting plugin like [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com/) ([there are more plugins like that out there](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/140/top-5-best-code-syntax-highlighter-javascript-plugins)).

All of them support highlight for SQL and a lot of programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://highlightjs.org/

162 languages and 74 styles
automatic language detection
multi-language code highlighting
available for node.js
works with any markup
compatible with any js framework